# How to change date format in .csv file in unix

Tags: linux, shell, csv, unix, unix-timestamp

I want to change the date format to `2013-08-01` and the current format in my file is `8/10/13` and the file contains thousands of records and i have bulk number of files as well.

Please suggest on this, how to convert.

```
+abcd 2013^8/1/13^Bing^Milwaukee_abcd High Volume^Abcd^izvd4PZo^^Wisconsin^Chicago^http://ad.abcd.net/clk;256581924;80198650;s;u=ms&sv1=izvd4PZo&sv2={AdId}&sv3=3392oik17016&sv4={keyword}&sv5={matchtype};?http://www.chicago.buyacar.com/specials?srchid=|Milwaukee_cdhdf+High+Volume|_%2Berhefn_2013^Broad^5^1^1.47^
 +sjhrejk models^8/1/13^Bing^Milwaukee_shdh High Volume^fhekj^9NT23JfC^^Wisconsin^Chicago^http://ad.fhd.net/clk;256581924;80198650;s;u=ms&sv1=9NT23JfC&sv2={AdId}&sv3=3392oik17016&sv4={keyword}&sv5={matchtype};?http://www.chicago.buyhfrkeu.com/specials?srchid=|Milwaukee_djkjfhkd+High+Volume|_%2Bdhk_models^Broad^14^4^5.58^
buy a +jkdsh^8/1/13^Bing^Milwaukee_kjfheu High Volume^jkdfhdj^T0ncFpv4^^Wisconsin^Chicago^http://ad.jfd.net/clk;256581924;80198650;s;u=ms&sv1=T0ncFpv4&sv2={AdId}&sv3=3392oik17016&sv4={keyword}&sv5={matchtype};?http://www.chicago.buyfjj.com/specials?srchid=|Milwaukee_jefrhjd+High+Volume|buy_a_%2Bfhd^Broad^15^1^2.44^
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace your date using `-d` to pass the current format and `"+..."` to indicate the new one:

```
$ date -d"8/10/13" "+%Y-%m-%d"
2013-08-10
```

To update all contents on your file with this format, keep reading lines, fetching these kind of fields and formatting them:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  mydate=$(grep -Po '[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+' <<< "$line") # gets 8/1/13
  # perform the replacement in case there is date to process
  if [[ ! -z "$mydate" ]]; then
     newdate=$(date -d"$mydate" "+%Y-%m-%d") # converts to 2013-08-01
     sed -i "s#$mydate#$newdate#" file       # replaces in the text (-i option)
  fi
done < file
```

Output based on your input:

```
+abcd 2013^2013-08-01^Bing^Milwaukee_abcd High Volume^Abcd^izvd4PZo^^Wisconsin^Chicago^http://ad.abcd.net/clk;256581924;80198650;s;u=ms&sv1=izvd4PZo&sv2={AdId}&sv3=3392oik17016&sv4={keyword}&sv5={matchtype};?http://www.chicago.buyacar.com/specials?srchid=|Milwaukee_cdhdf+High+Volume|_%2Berhefn_2013^Broad^5^1^1.47^
 +sjhrejk models^2013-08-01^Bing^Milwaukee_shdh High Volume^fhekj^9NT23JfC^^Wisconsin^Chicago^http://ad.fhd.net/clk;256581924;80198650;s;u=ms&sv1=9NT23JfC&sv2={AdId}&sv3=3392oik17016&sv4={keyword}&sv5={matchtype};?http://www.chicago.buyhfrkeu.com/specials?srchid=|Milwaukee_djkjfhkd+High+Volume|_%2Bdhk_models^Broad^14^4^5.58^
buy a +jkdsh^2013-08-01^Bing^Milwaukee_kjfheu High Volume^jkdfhdj^T0ncFpv4^^Wisconsin^Chicago^http://ad.jfd.net/clk;256581924;80198650;s;u=ms&sv1=T0ncFpv4&sv2={AdId}&sv3=3392oik17016&sv4={keyword}&sv5={matchtype};?http://www.chicago.buyfjj.com/specials?srchid=|Milwaukee_jefrhjd+High+Volume|buy_a_%2Bfhd^Broad^15^1^2.44^
```

Comment: +1 .... **BUT** your answer didn't solve OP's problem, OP wants `8/10/13` -> `2013-08-01` not `2013-08-10`  :D :D... (I believe it is a typo)

Comment: Haha then we can try with `echo 2013-08-01` :))

Comment: @Dileep check updated answer. I added a condition to skip lines without date.

Comment: @fedorqui Can't i give Multiple files at a time? Error : -bash: KeywordsClicksgreaterthan0*.csv: ambiguous redirect

Comment: @Dileep no, the expression `while ... do ... done < file` just accepts one file at a time. You can wrap my code inside a bigger block with something like `for file in KeywordsClicksgreaterthan0*.csv; do while ... do ... done < $file; done`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for that.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='^'
while read -ra LINE; do
    LINE[1]=$(exec date -d "${LINE[1]}" '+%F')
    echo "${LINE[*]}"
done
```

Save it to a file and run `bash script.sh < your_file > output`.

Example output:

```
+abcd 2013^2013-08-01^Bing^Milwaukee_abcd High Volume^Abcd^izvd4PZo^^Wisconsin^Chicago^http://ad.abcd.net/clk;256581924;80198650;s;u=ms&sv1=izvd4PZo&sv2={AdId}&sv3=3392oik17016&sv4={keyword}&sv5={matchtype};?http://www.chicago.buyacar.com/specials?srchid=|Milwaukee_cdhdf+High+Volume|_%2Berhefn_2013^Broad^5^1^1.47
 +sjhrejk models^2013-08-01^Bing^Milwaukee_shdh High Volume^fhekj^9NT23JfC^^Wisconsin^Chicago^http://ad.fhd.net/clk;256581924;80198650;s;u=ms&sv1=9NT23JfC&sv2={AdId}&sv3=3392oik17016&sv4={keyword}&sv5={matchtype};?http://www.chicago.buyhfrkeu.com/specials?srchid=|Milwaukee_djkjfhkd+High+Volume|_%2Bdhk_models^Broad^14^4^5.58
buy a +jkdsh^2013-08-01^Bing^Milwaukee_kjfheu High Volume^jkdfhdj^T0ncFpv4^^Wisconsin^Chicago^http://ad.jfd.net/clk;256581924;80198650;s;u=ms&sv1=T0ncFpv4&sv2={AdId}&sv3=3392oik17016&sv4={keyword}&sv5={matchtype};?http://www.chicago.buyfjj.com/specials?srchid=|Milwaukee_jefrhjd+High+Volume|buy_a_%2Bfhd^Broad^15^1^2.44
```

Another form (makes sure line ends with ^):

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='^'
while read -r LINE; do
    read -ra TOKENS <<< "$LINE"
    TOKENS[1]=$(exec date -d "${TOKENS[1]}" '+%F')
    if [[ $LINE == *^ ]]; then
        echo "${TOKENS[*]}^"
    else
        echo "${TOKENS[*]}"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
+abcd 2013^2013-08-01^Bing^Milwaukee_abcd High Volume^Abcd^izvd4PZo^^Wisconsin^Chicago^http://ad.abcd.net/clk;256581924;80198650;s;u=ms&sv1=izvd4PZo&sv2={AdId}&sv3=3392oik17016&sv4={keyword}&sv5={matchtype};?http://www.chicago.buyacar.com/specials?srchid=|Milwaukee_cdhdf+High+Volume|_%2Berhefn_2013^Broad^5^1^1.47^
 +sjhrejk models^2013-08-01^Bing^Milwaukee_shdh High Volume^fhekj^9NT23JfC^^Wisconsin^Chicago^http://ad.fhd.net/clk;256581924;80198650;s;u=ms&sv1=9NT23JfC&sv2={AdId}&sv3=3392oik17016&sv4={keyword}&sv5={matchtype};?http://www.chicago.buyhfrkeu.com/specials?srchid=|Milwaukee_djkjfhkd+High+Volume|_%2Bdhk_models^Broad^14^4^5.58^
buy a +jkdsh^2013-08-01^Bing^Milwaukee_kjfheu High Volume^jkdfhdj^T0ncFpv4^^Wisconsin^Chicago^http://ad.jfd.net/clk;256581924;80198650;s;u=ms&sv1=T0ncFpv4&sv2={AdId}&sv3=3392oik17016&sv4={keyword}&sv5={matchtype};?http://www.chicago.buyfjj.com/specials?srchid=|Milwaukee_jefrhjd+High+Volume|buy_a_%2Bfhd^Broad^15^1^2.44^
```